# How to install the moveit library ?

Tags: software-installation, gpu, kdenlive, media-library

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on an intel cpu with a gtx1050 gpu. 
The GPU option in Kdenlive is grey-out, I have to install the moveit library in order to make the use of a GPU available.

However,

```
apt-get install moveit
```

has no effect, 
so I googled for a tutorial on how to install it, 
there were a few and they had different names after apt-get install
and had further commands, 
more complicated than a simple apt-get install command.

I tried them all, but with no positive result.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is `movit` rather than `moveit`? The binary package appears to be called `libmovit4`

Comment: thx, this could be the breakthrough, I ll try apt-get install libmovit4

Comment: hmmm, I checked with   dpkg -l libmovit4   and it is already installed

Comment: i started both,  first this one, because I wrongly assumed I dont have movit installed, however when I checked with dpkg -l that i have it, I realized this question was on wrong assumptions, so I wrote the question you linked to. If I could choose, I would like to have this here closed and the other opened.   I checked if i can delete this but I am not allowed.