# How can I enable the GPU in Kdenlive?

Tags: gpu, kdenlive, media-library

my system:

- intel cpu
- gtx 1050 ti
- ubuntu suite 16.04
- kdenlive 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1  (got this with dpkg -l, think it is the version)

The GPU option in Kdenlive is greyed out, I read I have to have the movit-library (libmovit4) installed in order to enable the GPU option.
Strangely, the movit library is already installed.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the moveit library ?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/904083/how-to-install-the-moveit-library)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice

Comment: @AndroidDev I'd suggest closing the other one (which seems to be the Y in this particular [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) )

Comment: but my movit library is already installed and the gpu is still greyed out

Comment: Do you have dual video cards? Are you using effects in your project?

Comment: I just have one GPU, I use different effects like BLUR,VERTIGO,CURVES,VIGNETTE...the effects work, but they would not work so slowly with a GPU enabled.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment this but I am also having the exact same problem, kdenlive has the GPU Processing greyed out when using a GTX1050Ti, even with libmovit installed and configured perfectly. It's super odd. I have used kdenlive before on a Laptop with HD4000 (not dedicated) graphics and it still wasn't greyed out for that computer so why is it greyed out with an actual dedicated GPU?

Comment: I activated GPU rendering in Kdenlive 17.08.2 (Ubuntu 17.10, i7 laptop with dual GPU - intel/nvidia GeForce GTX 950M; only open source drivers are installed). On my system, it takes 3-4-6 times  longer to render a HD 1.3 minutes clip with GPU rendering. So, for me it makes no sense to do that as it is much slower. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this (finally) by:
- adding the ppa https://launchpad.net/~kdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable
- reinstalling melt